# scipy.optimize.minimize convergence issues

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy

I have a function that I wish to optimize, but that is returning `nan`s.

Here is the function (`fnRestrictParams` is a helper function):

```
def fnRestrictParams(vParams):
    vRestrictedParams = vParams
    vRestrictedParams[1] = exp(vParams[1])
    vRestrictedParams[2] = exp(vParams[2]) / (1 + exp(vParams[2]))
    return(vRestrictedParams)


def fnGASGaussianCopulaLikelihood(vParams, iT, mData):
    dLL = 0  # initialize the likelihood at zero
    vRestrictedParams = fnRestrictParams(vParams)
    dOmega = vRestrictedParams[0]
    dA = vRestrictedParams[1]
    dB = vRestrictedParams[2]

    dFactor = dOmega
    dOmega = dOmega*(1 - dB)
    vFactor = np.zeros(iT)
    for t in range(iT):
        # compute the copula parameters based on the factors
        rho = (1 - exp(-dFactor))/(1 + exp(-dFactor))
        rho2 = rho * rho
        vFactor[t] = rho

        # quantile functions
        qu = sps.norm.ppf(mData[t, :])
        x = qu[0] ** 2 + qu[1] ** 2
        y = qu[0] * qu[1]

        # get the log pdf of the copula, and its gradient with respect to the copula parameters
        dLL += -0.5 * np.log(1 - rho2) - 0.5 * (rho2 * x - 2 * rho * y) / (1 - rho2)

        # scaled score function
        dSt = (2 / (1 - rho2)) * (y - rho - rho * (x - 2) / (1 + rho2))

        # GAS recursion
        dFactor = dOmega + dA * dSt + dB * dFactor
    dLL = dLL/iT
    return(-dLL)
```

The data to test this function is [here](https://gist.github.com/fgnu/5e63b456d780eeb9a141#file-patton4filtered-csv).

I know that this function works correctly, because I have compared the output to an implementation available from the original authors (in another programming language).

```
# load the data
mData = np.loadtxt("./Data/Patton4filtered.csv",
           skiprows=1, usecols = tuple(range(1, 4)), delimiter = ",")

# test the likelihood function
for x in np.arange(3.1, 4, .1):
    print(fnGASGaussianCopulaLikelihood([x, -5, 5.0], mData.shape[0], mData[:, [0, 1]]))
```

However, when I try to optimize this function using `scipy.optimize.minimize`:

```
# optimize the function without the gradient
spoGC = spo.minimize(fnGASGaussianCopulaLikelihood, np.array([0.005,-5,5.0]),
                     args = (int(mData.shape[0]), mData[:, [0, 1]]),
             method = 'BFGS', options = {'disp': True, 'gtol': 1e-10, 'eps': 1e-10})
```

I get:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: nan
         Iterations: 0
         Function evaluations: 5
         Gradient evaluations: 1
Out[34]: 
(array([ 0.005     ,  1.0067607 ,  0.72974065]),
 nan,
 array([ nan,  nan,  nan]),
 array([[1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1]]),
 5,
 1,
 0)
```

which is clearly no good. I am unable to figure out what is causing this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, the function is returning `nan`, so there IS a problem with it. Debug the minimization code stopping just inside the function. Copy the input of the function which is causing the nan somewhere. Then you know with which values the function is not working and you can further investigate how your function fails.

Comment: @gg349 You are absolutely right. The question then is how should I handle `NaN`s. I coded the same function in R, and R's BFGS implementation had no issues. Should I check within the function whether a `NaN` is being returned, and set it to some large positive values to dissuade BFGS from trying to explore that part of the parameter space? Is there a more robust (e.g. R's `optim`) implementation of BFGS in Python that moves back to the last step when encountering `NaN`s? I can supply the R code if necessary.

Comment: 1) yes, that's one option and I would go for that; 2) I do not see why this solution is not robust; 3) I do not know how `optim` from R handles nans and I can't imagine how that may work, but I can't see how this is a good feature, it takes away the power from you. Simply put, I do not know of any optimization algorithms targeting functions returning invalid values. And this argument goes beyond coding.